# How to convert two observable items to another observable object with mapped values of two initial observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

These are the input observables:

```
items$ = of([
  {name: 'John', age: 30, job: 'Dentist', address: {street: 'Maple (6,103)', country: 'US'},
  {name: 'Mark', age: 34, job: 'Driver', address: {street: 'Pine (6,170)', country: 'US'}},
  {name: 'Johannes', age: 25, job: 'Mechanic', address: {street: 'Elm (5,233)', country: 'US'}},
  {name: 'Thjoma', age: 28, job: 'Coder', address: {street: 'Lake (4,901)', country: 'US'}},
])

fields$ = of([
  name, age, street
])
```

How to map above observables fields to a new object for each item and return new array?

Expected Result:

```
of([
  {name: 'John', age: 30, job: 'Dentist', street: 'Maple (6,103)'},
  {name: 'Mark', age: 34, job: 'Driver', street: 'Pine (6,170)'},
  {name: 'Johannes', age: 25, job: 'Mechanic', street: 'Elm (5,233)'},
  {name: 'Thjoma', age: 28, job: 'Coder', street: 'Lake (4,901)'},
])
```

See the inside items (street) are mapped/ flattened to get new object for each items.

I've tried out something like this:
But it is not working.

```
    return combineLatest(
      this.items$,
      this.fields$,
      (items, fields) => ({ items, fields })
    ).pipe(
      map(({ items, fields }) =>
        fields.reduce(
          (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: items.map((item) => item[cur]) }),
          {}
        )
      )
    );
```

Can someone help?

**SEE THAT**

Only fields from the observable fields$ is appearing in the resulting observable.
Others are omitted.

Comment: Do you really need field list as *observable*? Isn't it just a set of interested fields? If so, use straightforward `map()` with fixed (or varying but not observable) set of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dynamic-object-shape)

```
const $specifiedFieldsOnly = combineLatest(this.items$, this.fields$).pipe(
  map(([items, fields]) => 
    items.map(item => (
      fields.reduce((obj, field) => ({ ...obj, [field]:item[field] }), {}))
    )
  )
);
```

Of course it will only work for field names that exist in the source data.  In your case `street` will not work because your objects don't have a `street` property.  You want to dig out the `address.street` property, so you have some work to do in order to make that work.

If you wanted to specify your field names with a dot to denote a nested property (e.g. `address.street`), this could work: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dynamic-object-shape-nested)

```
const fields$ = of([
  'name', 'age', 'address.street', 'address.country'
]);

const $specifiedFieldsOnly = combineLatest(this.items$, this.fields$).pipe(
  map(([items, fields]) => 
    items.map(item => (
      fields.reduce((obj, path) => {
        const field = path.split('.').reduce(
          (acc, cur, i) => { 
            const name = cur;
            const value = (i === 0) ? item[cur] : acc.value[cur];

            return { name, value };
          },
          { name: undefined, value: undefined }
        );

        return { ...obj, [field.name]: field.value };

      }, {}))
    )
  )
);
```

Note: you'd need to be a little more elaborate if you're concerned about duplicate field names.